# Error when running query in backand: not a valid constant

Tags: backand

Hi when working in Backand I try to run the following query: 
{ 
    "object": "dr_persons",
    "q": { 
        "person_type" : "4"
    },
    "fields": ["first_name", "last_name"] 
}
person_type is a table in mysql db with "4" as a value.

When I run it I get this error:
Errors in Query
Please fix the following errors in the query:

not a valid constant for field person_type of object dr_persons

The only thing I can see is that when I sync my db it makes it a "float" which I can't change.  Can anyone give me some direction on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is due to the constant `"4"` being a string. According to the field type, float, it should be a number. Hence your query should be:

```
{ 
   "object": "dr_persons", 
   "q": { 
      "person_type" : 4
   }, 
   "fields": ["first_name", "last_name"] 
}
```